# How to check database if ticket exists ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a restaurant system in ruby and currently working on a ticket controller the way its set up now every time the user clicks add to ticket it creates a new ticket every time. I want it to so when the user clicks add to ticket it checks if a ticket exists in the database and if it doesn't it creates a new one and if it exists it adds on to the same ticket. I'm not quite sure how to approach it.

```
class TicketController < ApplicationController


  def addToTicket
    session[:tableID] = "15"
    unless defined? check
        check = Ticket.create(
        table: session[:tableID],
        tax: "8.25",
        tstatus: 0
        )   
        session[:ticket] = check
        puts("**********Ticket created************")
        redirect_to guest_path
    else
        check.orderItems.create(
            item: (MenuItem.find_by id: params[:item_id]),
            ingredients: params[:good_ingredients],
            notes: params[:notes],
            istatus: 0
        )
        session[:ticket] = check
        puts("**************Ticket added to***********")
        redirect_to guest_path
    end
end
```

Comment: random code style comment: `item: (MenuItem.find_by id: params[:item_id])` should be `item: MenuItem.find_by(id: params[:item_id])` (parentheses around the wrong thing)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev depends, really. They delimit a hash value here. Still, I would agree, and [community style guide would, too](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-dsl-parens).

Comment: About these `puts` for debugging: get some [`pry` and `pry-byebug`](http://pryrepl.org/) instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do this with [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) in your model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tickets
end

#app/models/ticket.rb
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :table
   validates :table, uniqueness: { scope: :user } # You didn't provide much context so this is quite generic
end

#app/models/table.rb
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tickets
   has_many :users, through: :tickets
end
```

This allows you to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :tables do
   resources :tickets
end

#app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @table  = Table.find params[:table_id]
     @ticket = current_user.tickets.new(table: @table)
   end

   def create
     @table = Table.find params[:table_id]
     @ticket = current_user.tickets.new ticket_params
     @ticket.save
   end

   private

   def ticket_params
     params.require(:ticket).permit(:tax, :tstatus, :table_id).merge(table_id: @table.id)
   end
end
```

---

## Notes

It's not a good idea to output in your controller (`puts`)... unless you like checking your logs a lot.

I *think* you're trying to invoke the [`flash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html) method:

```
def create
   flash[:success] = "Ticket Created"
end
```

--

You also need to make sure you're calling the correct *actions* from your views...

You're currently using `addToticket` (which should be in [`snake_case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)) - the equivalent to `update`. Instead of what you have, I would recommend using `new/create` and `update` actions independently:

```
#app/controllers/tables_controller.rb
class TablesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @table  = Table.find params[:id]
      @ticket = current_user.tickets.find_by(table_id: params[:id]) || current_user.tickets.new(table: @table)
   end
end

#app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @table = Table.find params[:id]
      @ticket = current_user.tickets.new ticket_params
      redirect_to @table if @ticket.save
   end

   def update
      @table = Table.find params[:id]
      @ticket = current_user.tickets.new ticket_params
      ## more logic here
      redirect_to @table if @ticket.save        
   end

   private

   def ticket_params
      params.require(:ticket).permit(:tstatus, :etc, :etc).merge(table_id: @table.id)
   end
end

#app/views/tables/show.html.erb
<%= form_for [@table, @ticket] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :tstatus %>
    ....
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The above will invoke a form and populate it with the appropriate fields according to the `Table` model. The *really* cool thing is that if you set it so that if no ticket exists, a "new" instance of the model will be invoked, sending the submission to the `create` action, else `update`.